# Can/Should I take a feral/stray cat with me to a new house?

Tags: cats, feral, house-moving, strays

2 years ago a nursing Mama cat appeared on my porch digging through garbage for a meal. I tried to pet her, but she ran away immediately and I did not see her for several days. Gradually she started coming back once I set food out. She comes when we call her and is very friendly with us, but will run when she sees anyone else.

We have 3 indoor cats who we've had since they were kittens and they are not fond of our outdoor kitty. Our neutered alpha male will start peeing on EVERYTHING if we were to let her in. We need to move far away and I'm worried about trying to take her with us, I would be terribly guilt stricken if we had to leave her here. We feed her twice a day and I don't know that she hunts much anymore.

There are other strays in the area that neighbors take care of, so we can't really leave her in the care of anyone else. She is NOT part of a colony of feral cats. I just want to do what is best for her without harming our 3 indoor kitties. Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: What is the question you are asking here? It's not clear to me what a good answer to this question might include. For example, are you asking how to integrate the feral cat with the others or are you asking about whether you can take the cat with you?

Comment: Was wondering if you took the cat with you? I’m facing the same dilemma with 2 ferals that I don’t want to desert, yet can’t have inside my home. If you did take her... how did you get her to stay at your new home?

Answer (score 4):

You should most definitely take the cat with you. The cat is dependent on you for food since you have been feeding her. If you are concerned about your cats being aggressive towards the stray, I would suggest that you allow her to be an outdoor cat (depending on where you are moving to, if you are moving to a suburban area that has lots of traffic or large predators you might have to consider finding someone to take care of her as an indoor cat).