# I have been feeding three feral cats for four years

Tags: cats, feral

We live in Hanover, PA in the USA and we were renting. They gave us notice to move. They are selling. We are moving in two weeks. I have been feeding for three feral cats for four years. I have asked everyone I know to take them. No one can. I'm afraid they will die now that they depend on us. I bought them little houses and I put a tent up all winter. I'm sorry I ever started. I feel so sad and if anyone can help me, please direct me to anyone who will help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered trying to trap and relocated them? It would also be a great opportunity to get them neutered (many vets offer a discounted service to neuter feral cats because it helps to prevent the feral colony growing larger).

Answer (score 6):

There are a few options.

1. Take them with you when you move see [How can I move houses with a friendly feral cat I care for?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10468/how-can-i-move-houses-with-a-friendly-feral-cat-i-care-for) & [Can/Should I take a feral/stray cat with me to a new house?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19592/can-should-i-take-a-feral-stray-cat-with-me-to-a-new-house)
2. If you owned the house, you could leave the cats and a message for the new owner, but that is probably not an option for you as a renter. There have been some cute stories shared on social media about this.
3. You could ask a neighbor but that is not always an option [see example](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21081/how-to-feed-outdoor-cats-when-youre-away-for-a-month)
4. You could contact a local cat rescue (this may or may not be a shelter). There are groups of people who specifically volunteer to help feral cats.  If they are made aware they can check on the cats, after you are gone, and if needed rescue them and rehome them.

Note that in some areas, feral cats are spayed and released, See [Why are cats released as part of "spay and release" programs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/why-are-cats-released-as-part-of-spay-and-release-programs)